# WebGL GLSL Shader Texture Transformation 2d

Tags: textures, glsl, webgl

I have a problem in using a texture in a fragment shader in WebGL.
This texture is clamped to the Fragment Coordinates (0 to 1) in both directions x and y. I would like to apply a transformation on this texture. Using scale rotate from the center of the screen and translation in [-1,1].

The shader is like:`gl_FragColor = texture2D( texture, transform );`

The transform is a vec2.
I have a radian angle in float.
I have a scale factor for x and y
Finally, I have a translate vector.

When I test it the texture goes in all the directions but never in the right way.
Can you give me the best matrix to do that and explain me step by step?

I have tested it in :  [Kick.js](http://www.kickjs.org/example/shader_editor/shader_editor.html)

This is the vertex shader used :

```
attribute vec3 vertex;
void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

And the fragment shader :

```
precision highp float;

uniform vec2 resolution;

uniform float angleInDegrees;
uniform vec2 scale;
uniform vec2 translate;

uniform sampler2D texture;

void main(void)
{
    vec3 coordinates;
         coordinates.x = gl_FragCoord.x / resolution.x;
         coordinates.y = gl_FragCoord.y / resolution.y;
         coordinates.z = 1.0;

    float angle = radians( angleInDegrees );

    mat3 transform; 
         transform = mat3(   scale.x * cos( angle ), scale.x * sin( angle ), 0.0,
                           - scale.y * sin( angle ), scale.y * cos( angle ), 0.0,

                          - 0.5 * scale.x * cos( angle ) + 0.5 * scale.y * sin( angle ) - 0.5 * translate.x + 0.5,  - 0.5 * scale.x * sin( angle ) - 0.5 * scale.y * cos( angle ) - 0.5 * translate.y + 0.5, 1.0);

    gl_FragColor = texture2D( texture, (  transform * coordinates ).xy );
}
```

The problem is when i rotate it's not rotated from the center of the texture, and when i scale the position of the texture doesn't appear to be correct !
Hope someone can help

Comment: When you *test* what? Show some code

Comment: [See this answer and the included samples and links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918751/clipping-images-in-webgl/29923831#29923831)

Comment: I found the problem, the translation and the translation to the origin were inversed, resolved